# What does "this" contain when using the "implements"?

Tags: android, oop, android-recyclerview

I am creating an interface in the android studio. I am doing the onClick functionality for my `RecyclerView`.

Here you can see my `HomeFragment`, which contains the `RecyclerView` and thus implements the method `onEventListener`.

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements HomeAdapter.onEventListener
```

I also had to change my constructor in the adapter.

```
  public HomeAdapter(Activity ctx, ArrayList<EventPost> Arr, onEventListener onEventListener) {
            this.ctx = ctx;
            this.items = Arr;
            this.mOnEventListener = onEventListener;
        }
```

For this reason, in my `HomeFragment.java` I had to change the arguments when initializing the `HomeAdapter`.

```
homeAdapter = new HomeAdapter(getActivity(),event_list, this);
```

Here I was able to use this, to pass the `onEventListener`. However, I also initialize the HomeAdapter later in the app, but this initialization lies in the method, which has "this" assigned to different things than the one before. For this reason, it does not work with this and requires `onEventListener` type of argument.

How would I change "this" in the second initialization, so that it works globally?

Comment: In your second initialization do you need "this" instance ?

Comment: It should not be an issue since this is one of the most routine ways of using interfaces. Do you have a compile issue or is it just the IDE generating a warning/error?

Comment: Use `HomeFragment.this` to refer to the instance of `HomeFragment` Globally in `HomeFragment`.

Comment: HomeFragment.this works! thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use HomeFragment.this in your second method.

`homeAdapter = new HomeAdapter(getActivity(),event_list, HomeFragment.this);`

Answer (score 0):

Try passing this with classname like
onEventListener.this 
instead of "this".

homeAdapter = new HomeAdapter(getActivity(),event_list, onEventListener.this);